# C++ классы.Как вернуть R1?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста вернуть R1.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
Rational Rational::operator-(const Rational& R0) const
{
    return Rational(m_m*...// Если бы вы, как приличный человек, привели
                           // вопрос текстом, я бы скопировал и дал полный код...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Извиняюсь,но я задаю вопрос в первый раз.Следующий раз всё будет  в правилах.